# iOS HealthKit to track real time sleep states

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I know that HealthKit can retrieve sleep states based on some samples given start and end time. But I wonder if it can give a current realtime status of the sleep state, meaning just retrieving the current state instead. Or is it using some algorithm and this requires several values and that's why all I can find is about taking samples with some time gap in middle?

```
let sleepSampleType = HKCategoryType(.sleepAnalysis)
let sleepCategory = HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis.asleepDeep.rawValue
let deepSleepSample  = HKCategorySample(type: sleepSampleType,
                                        value:sleepCategory,
                                        start: startDate,
                                        end: endDate)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sleep stages data is not available in real-time. You can only read it after the user wakes up and the samples are written.

Comment: Thanks for commenting on this, Im sorry I didnt know this, it is not in the docs or I havent found this particular data, then its only data available when the user wakes up and stop the app to track the sleep? I mean the process I assume is when user stops the app to track the sleep then the samples are written and available to other apps? so there is no way to track in real time sleep states?

Comment: Also I would like to contact you if possible in relation to this and something I would like to propose, let me know if there is a way